# How to use Multiple routes in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router, jsx

```
//Prev.jsx

const handleClick = (row) =>{
  const orderNumber = row.orderNumber.replace(/\D/g, '')
  console.log(orderNumber)
  navigate("/drivers/" + (driverId) + "/" + (orderNumber))
}



//App.js

<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="drivers">
    <Route index element={
      <RequaireAuth>
        <Dlist/>
      </RequaireAuth>}>
    </Route>
    <Route path=":driverId" element={<RequaireAuth>
      <PrevSingle/>
    </RequaireAuth>}>
    <Route path="/drivers/driverId/:orderNumber" element={
      <RequaireAuth>
        <PrevSingle/>
      </RequaireAuth>
    }>
    </Route>
  </Route>
</Route>
```

i got this error `No routes matched location /drivers/DEiXkSyMo8Sg2RtvS....../4662....`

i tried this way to  `Uncaught Error: Absolute route path "/:orderNumber" nested under path "/drivers/:driverId" is not valid. An absolute child route path must start with the combined path of all its parent routes.`

How to Navigate Multiple Routes Using react-router

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="drivers">
      <Route index element={
        <RequaireAuth>
          <Dlist/>
        </RequaireAuth>
      }>
      </Route>
      <Route path=":driverId" element={
        <RequaireAuth>
          <PrevSingle/>
        </RequaireAuth>
      }>
      <Route path="/:orderNumber" element={
        <PrevSingle/>
      }>
      </Route>
    </Route>
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

and without `/` like this `:orderNumber` it will not navigate but will not give any errors also, so what is the wright way to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path `"/drivers/DEiXkSyMo8Sg2RtvS....../4662...."` isn't matched because there is  no route path for the `"/drivers/DEiXkSyMo8Sg2RtvS......"` prefix part. From what I can tell though you meant for there to be a dynamic `"/drivers/:driverId"` route as the parent route for `"/drivers/:driverId/:orderNumber"` route.

If you want to use nested routes then the parent routes should render an `Outlet` for the nested routes to render their content into, and the nested routes should omit any leading `"/"` characters so they are specifying relative paths.

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="drivers">
      <Route
        index // <-- "/drivers"
        element={(
          <RequaireAuth>
            <Dlist />
          </RequaireAuth>
        )}
      />
      <Route
        path=":driverId" // <-- "/drivers/:driverId"
        element={(
          <RequaireAuth>
            <PrevSingle/> // <-- renders <Outlet />
          </RequaireAuth>
        )}
      >
        <Route
          path=":orderNumber" // <-- "/drivers/:driverId/:orderNumber"
          element={<PrevSingle />} // <-- rendered into parent's outlet
        />
      </Route>
    </Route>
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

If you want to render as sibling routes then the paths should be fully qualified (*note the paths are still relative from the parent route*), no `Outlet` is required.

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="drivers">
      <Route
        index // <-- "/drivers"
        element={(
          <RequaireAuth>
            <Dlist />
          </RequaireAuth>
        )}
      />
      <Route
        path=":driverId" // <-- "/drivers/:driverId"
        element={(
          <RequaireAuth>
            <PrevSingle/>
          </RequaireAuth>
        )}
      />
      <Route
        path=":driverId/:orderNumber" // <-- "/drivers/:driverId/:orderNumber"
        element={<PrevSingle />}
      />
    </Route>
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: thank you very much, i was struggling for days i'm new to react native this one worked just fine `path=":driverId/:orderNumber"`